# Scalac command line parameters in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, continuations

Scala includes the continuations plugin now (yay), but must be enabled by passing "-P:continuations:enable" to the scala compiler.  Is there a way to pass arbitrary arguments to scalac for the eclipse scala plugin?

From: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/19439

> the plugin is loaded by default, but
>   it must be enabled by the command line
>   argument -P:continuations:enable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add an option to enable continuations ASAP. Open an enhancement ticket for it in Trac so it doesn't get forgotten about.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll open a ticket.  But, does this mean there is no way to pass options to the compiler that aren't anticipated by the eclipse plugin?

Comment: At the moment there's no way to pass general arguments to the compiler. The compiler options dialog really needs to be completely reworked ... as ever, patches would be very welcome.

Comment: Support now added. Just add "continuations:enable" to the new "P" compiler setting field.

Comment: This change appeared in the 20100322... update today, and it works.  Thanks!